# how to get true if combobox.text match with its list items

Tags: c#, combobox, matching

i want to get true if combobox1.text matches with its list items and then further function . but if not the warning message to user .. so far i have tried

```
      bool itemExists = false;
    foreach (object obj in comboBox1.Items)
    {
        itemExists = obj.Equals(comboBox1.Text);
        if (itemExists)
        {
            itemExists = true;
        }
        break;

    }

    if (itemExists)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("good00");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("sorry no value");
    }
}
```

and also

```
    bool test ;
    test = comboBox1.Items.OfType<object>().Any(cbi => cbi.Equals(comboBox1.Text));

    if (test)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("values matched");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not matched");
    }
```

but i am not getting what  i desired ..
it should work as , it checks the combobox .text with its list, if any match then return true and that true values used further function. if their is no match it return false and that false used to send error message ..

any suggestion ..

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This statement does nothing:

```
if (itemExists)
{
    itemExists = true;
}
```

The `break` right after it is *unconditional*. Moving it inside the `if` condition will fix the problem:

```
if (itemExists)
{
    break;
}
```

Your second approach should work unmodified for objects of type `string`. To change it to work with objects of all types, use

```
test = comboBox1
    .Items.OfType<object>()
    .Any(cbi => cbi.ToString() == comboBox1.Text);
```

To display message only when there is no match use

```
if (!itemExists)
{
    MessageBox.Show("sorry no value");
}
```

Comment: thanks , but how to display message if their is no matched value.

Comment: @speedyraz I don't understand the meaning of the paragraph that you added in the edit: your method does not return anything; you cannot "return and then use the value", because once you return, you're out of that method. If you want to exit on no-match, put `return;` in the conditional after `MessageBox.Show` call.